# fabric-ca-client csr.names from ldap

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have connected my ca server to ldap. I can enroll users successfully, but csr names is fabric's defaults.

```
  names:
    - C: US
      ST: North Carolina
      L:
      O: Hyperledger
      OU: Fabric
```

I can config fabric-ca-client-config.yaml to change the parameters but I want to fetch these parameters from ldap.

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I solve it by using ldapsearch package.

```
function read_data(){
   echo $(ldapsearch  -h ldap_server -D "admin dn" -w adminpw -b "base name"   "(uid=user_uid)" $1  |  sed -n "s/$1: //gp")
}

c=$(read_data c)
o=$(read_data o)
st=$(read_data st)
```

then with this data I enroll the user

```
FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=. fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u https://user:passwd@ldap_server --tls.certfiles TLS_CA/hyperledger/crypto/ca-cert.pem --mspdir $PWD/tls --csr.names "C=$c,ST=$st,O=$o"
```

if anyone can suggest a direct method to fetch these data I will appreciate it.